# Choosing an inductor for DC-DC

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter, inductor

While simulating [tps54719](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54719.pdf?ts=1620842421098) in https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/, for my specific application, the simulator suggested IDC in the range 9.1A to 15.75A.

Is there a logical explanation to why would the simulator prefer a IDC to be higher than the maximum amperage the DC-DC can provide (7A)?

I also get confused between IDC and ISAT, I understood that IDC is equivalent to *Current Rating* which can be applied at a constant rate without thermal damage, while ISAT is the saturation current is where the Inductance drops to a specified level in the datasheet.

Is it okay to choose an inductor with ISAT=24A while the simulator is asking for IDC in the range 9.1A to 15.75A? Is there an disadvantage of choosing an inductor with *too high* ISAT relative to IDC?

Comment: You need to choose an inductor for your _peak_ current at worst case scenario. Have you simulated your converter? As for choosing too high, the only disadvantage is cost and size.

Comment: Converter datasheet shows max current of 10.5A @vin of 5v, it can effectively increases at higher input voltages." Is there an disadvantage of choosing an inductor with too high ISAT relative to IDC?" 》if you can accommodate higher value inductors at the cost of space with other specifications (srf,rdc,lmin)meeting you can keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TPS54719 is a Synchronous Step Down Converter with internal MOSFETs.

Quoted from sec. 7.1: "The integrated 30 mΩ MOSFETs allow for high efficiency power supply designs with continuous output currents up to 7 A". Not crystal clear because it suggests a continuous current of 7A per MOSFET, but you have duty cycle, so you could go beyond that.

The current rating is shown vs. temperature in Fig. 17 & 18 of the datasheet.
[image]

There is also "overcurrent protection" and "reverse overcurrent protection". The current limit in the datasheet is 10.5 A (typ) => typical! see below for margins on inductor current.

In the design example TI says "the RMS inductor current is 7.017 A and the peak inductor current is 7.84 A. The chosen inductor is a Würth 744311150 1.5 μH. It has a saturation current rating of 14 A (30% inductance loss) and an RMS current rating of 11 A ( 40 ºC temperature rise)." As you see, one thing is RMS current (causing heating) and one thing is saturation current (causing inductance reduction, and further increase of the flowing current). The margins for the selection of the inductor are significant as it should be. The reasons? First, all such parameters are approximate. Then, saturation is measured as an already 30% reduction of inductance: you should stay clear off that. Third, in case of transient peak output current you need some margin.

"The current flowing through the inductor is the inductor ripple current plus the output current." is also not such a clear sentence, because the ripple may be peak ripple, peak-peak ripple, or else. @winny spoke of "peak current".

Last remark: to say the obvious, 1 peak of current does not heat your MOSFETs (one switching cycle only, or a few), but saturates your inductor.

So, yes, 24A saturation current is a conservative choice. Unless, you know, too expensive, too large, not available with the desired range of inductance values.